# Probability of an ordered extraction

Tags: probability

There are `100` numbered objects from `1` to `100`. We extract `3` of these objects one after the other without reinsertion. Calculate the probability `P(a<b<c)`

The number of arrangements of three objects is `50∗49∗48` but the first number `a` must be `a < 99` while `b` must be `a < b < 100` What's the next step?

Comment: so it's just like extraction of three objects then choosing an order, note that all orders  are equiprobable

Comment: I don't understand can you give more details? The combinations of 3 objects are $\binom{100}{3}$

Comment: Deliberate duplicate.